# Run a python script in the background

Tags: python, python-2.7, console, subprocess

I have got 5 different scripts, these should be running in sequences. The 3.script needs to be open in the separate cmd line screen and continue with next script.
For instance;

1- Script
2- Script
3- Script ( Should be open new cmd screen and running from there)

```
p = subprocess.Popen("C:\\Master.bat", creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
raw_input('Enter to exit from this launcher script...')
```

While 3. script is running, I would like my script to run 4th and 5th script simultaneously. As 3. script is going to grab the logs.
4- Script
5- Script

If I do not close the 3rd cmd screen, it does not run the next script (4th Script).

Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does 4 and 5 in any way require or are they in any way dependent on the cmd window being opened? Or can you run then before opening the window?

Comment: Thanks @geostocker. There is no connection between them. After opening the 3.script in the new cmd screen, that should  be running in the background. And next step 4. script should be running after that.

Comment: Then you might have to look into some sort of threading / processing. Ie. spawn a thread that handles 3 separately. I'm not very familiar with Python's threading functionality, but it shouldn't be that big of a deal as long as you aren't working with (im)mutable objects.